# How to connect window.location.reload() with bootstrap button

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: 'http://dbtest.php'
  });
});
```

I have a problem with window.location.reload(), becouse when i click the button  "Reload" then everything works. However, I would like to share the "Reload" was performed when you click the "Products". I have tried in various ways to achieve this, however, does not work. Please help. Thanks

```
<body>
      <div>
        <img src ="img/logo.jpg" class="produkt logo" />
    </div>
    <button onclick="window.location.reload()">Reload</button>
    <br />
    <br />
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 margin-top-10">
           <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-sm-offset-4 col-xs-offset-1 col-md-4 col-sm-5 col-xs-11">
           <div class="app-button">
           <div class="app-button-content">
           <a href="Produkty.html" id="someElement"><img src="img/produkty.png" class="ikona" /></a>
            <p class="text-center">Produkty</p>
         </div>
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div id="products">
    <img src ="img/logo.jpg" class="produkt logo" />
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).on('click', '#products > img', function() {
    location.reload();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
<body>
      <div>
        <img src ="img/logo.jpg" class="produkt logo" onclick="window.location.reload()" />
    </div>
    <button onclick="window.location.reload()">Reload</button>
    <br />
    <br />
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 margin-top-10">
           <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-sm-offset-4 col-xs-offset-1 col-md-4 col-sm-5 col-xs-11">
           <div class="app-button">
           <div class="app-button-content">
           <a href="Produkty.html" id="someElement"><img src="img/produkty.png" class="ikona" /></a>
            <p class="text-center">Produkty</p>
         </div>
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```